# AWS API Gateway doesn't pass the HTTP data

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, aws-lambda, gateway

Basically, I'm making a serverless API using Lambda. I have this method:

[image]

As you can see, this method is using Lambda Proxy, so I would expect that my Lambda function would receive the request data, but somehow, this function:

```js
exports.handler = async (event, ctx) => 
{
    return [event, ctx];
};
```

Has the response is:

```json
[
    {
        "name": "dada",
        "email": "dada@dada.com",
        "message": "haha"
    },
    {
        "callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop": true,
        "functionVersion": "$LATEST",
        "functionName": "******-contact-form",
        "memoryLimitInMB": "128",
        "logGroupName": "/aws/lambda/******-contact-form",
        "logStreamName": "2022/01/20/[$LATEST]d65e9483c8d544c4976d91ff5875b11d",
        "invokedFunctionArn": "arn:aws:lambda:eu-central-1:252365724355:function:******-contact-form",
        "awsRequestId": "681b4362-89a3-426c-a194-06173c3ec4ed"
    }
]
```

I have other methods (with GET verbose) and using Lambda Proxy I receive all the details from the request. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: How do you invoke the API?

Comment: @Marcin using Postman and in the body I select `raw`, JSON type and pass that object you can see in the response.

Comment: Can you also share the information you're expecting as mentioned in the question.

Comment: @HussainMansoor on another method (with GET verbose) the event is like https://pastebin.com/sNmtFugs

Comment: You could try logging the value server side to see if the event contains the data when it reaches the lambda.

Comment: Lambda proxy functions require a specific response format: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-lambda-proxy-integrations.html#api-gateway-simple-proxy-for-lambda-output-format 

When I simply return [event, ctx] from a proxy lambda I get an internal server error. Are you sure you are testing the correct endpoint and lambda?

Comment: Solved, I forgot to deploy it...